# Javascript and html slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I put together this slide show in notepad++ and html and the pictures wont change when I test my website. Please help me change it to work. Also if you have any videos that might help those will work too. Does the editing software matter?

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xht ml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var image1=new image()
 image1.src="theimage.png"
 var image2=new image()
 image2.src="soccerafrica.png"
 var image3=new image()
 image3.src="thatsall.png"

</script>
<style> 
body.border{ border-style:solid; 
border-width:20px;
border-color:#3C3;
margin: 0px;
}

@font-face{font-family: habara; 
src: Harabara.ttf;}
div{font-family: habara; }


ul { list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
    }
li { display: inline-block;
width:250px;
margin: 0px; 
}

</style>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Kinectricity</title>
</head>
<body class="border">
<p><pre>
</pre>
</p>

<h1 style="font-size:30px; background-color:#F90; margin:0px">

<ul> 
<center>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><img src="thatsall.png"height="145"width="145"</li>
    <li><a href="">Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</center>

</ul>
</h1>
<p>
<pre>

</pre>
</p>
<center>
<h2 style="font-size: 50px; color:#7C3; margin:0px"><div>K  i  n  e  c  t  r  i  c  i  t  y</div></h2>
</center>
<p>
<pre>

</pre>
</p>
<image src="theimage.png" name="slideshow" alt="imageslideshow" height="225" width="350">
<script type="text/javascript">
var numberImage = 1
function myslide()
{
document.images.slideshow.src=eval("image"+numberImage+".src")
if(numberImage < 3)
numberImage = numberImage + 1 
else
numberImage = 1
setTimeout("myslide()" ,5000)
}
myslide()
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The editing software does not matter but you should debug your code using the available browser developer tools (aka Inspector, Ctrl+Shift+I) to single-step through your Javascript and examine the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you forgot to add ";" on the end of the statements in the first block of scripting?
Like this:

var image1=new image();
   image1.src="theimage.png";
   var image2=new image();
   image2.src="soccerafrica.png";
   var image3=new image();
   image3.src="thatsall.png";

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is a great editor. Many of us use it as our primary editor/IDE.

This code should work for you:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jqt64q5a/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<h1 style="font-size:30px; background-color:#F90; margin:0px">
  <ul> 
  <center>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><img src="http://placeimg.com/145/145/animals"height="145" width="145"</li>
      <li><a href="">Order</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </center>
  </ul>
</h1>
<h2 style="font-size: 50px; color:#7C3; margin:0px"><div>K  i  n  e  c  t  r  i  c  i  t  y</div></h2>
<image id="ss" src="http://placeimg.com/225/350/animals" name="slideshow" alt="imageslideshow" height="225" width="350">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
var numberImage = 0;
var arr = ["http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals","http://placeimg.com/48/50/animals","http://placeimg.com/50/49/animals"];
$(function(){
    myslide(numberImage);
});

function myslide(numberImage){
  $('#ss').attr('src', arr[numberImage])
  numberImage++;
  if (numberImage>2) numberImage=0;
  setTimeout(function(){myslide(numberImage)} ,3000);
}
```

---

Note that the jsFiddle has a `rpt` DIV into which the next image name is placed, just for you to see. In your project, replace the URL images in that array with your own image names, thus:

```
var arr = ["img/image1.png","img/image2.png","img/image3.png"];
```